# Is there a simple way to convert a signed char to an int without sign extension?

Tags: c

In C, I would like to convert a `signed char` to an `int`, *without* sign extension. So if the `signed char` is 0xFF, the `int` would also be 0xFF. Simply casting to an int won't work; the result would be 0xFFFFFFFF (on a 32-bit machine).

This seems to work (and is already pretty simple):

```
int convert(signed char sc) {
    return 0xFF & (int) sc; 
}
```

But is there a simpler or more idiomatic way?

**Edit:** Fixed function

Comment: Your implementation might allow you to do this via *type punning* — that is, using a union containing both types, assigning to the `char` and then reading from the `int`. This is implementation defined behaviour though (ie. you'd need to read your compiler manual's appendix), and you're probably far better off with a portable solution, which is why this isn't written up as an answer.

Comment: "Sign extension" is not what's taking place; the value is simply being preserved. If you want to change the value, perform an arithmetic operation to do so. In particular it looks like you want to reduce modulo 256 to the range [0,255).

Comment: To add to @R.'s comment, if your signed char is 8 bits then as far as C is concerned its value is *never* `0xFF`, which is exactly equivalent to 255 - its maximum value is `0x7f`.

Comment: @R Isn't that just a matter of semantics? At least on a twos-complement machine, sign extension will preserve the value, right?

Comment: However, I think a better way to express what I want to do is that I want to take a signed char, and produce an int who's low-order bits are identical with the signed char, and high-order bits are all zero. And I certainly should have used -1 as the sample value for the signed char!

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You can cast to `unsigned char` first.  Assuming a definition:

```
signed char c;
```

You could just do:

```
int i = (unsigned char)c;
```

Comment: Thanks, I think this makes the intent the clearest (seems obvious once you see it).

Answer (score 0):

You can also use an union (the behavior is implementation-defined, but it's largely supported by the compilers).

```
int
convert(signed char ch)
{
    union {
        signed char c1;
        int c2;
    } input = { ch };
    return input.c2;
}
```

Or, as Carl Norum said, you can simply cast to `unsigned char` :

```
int 
convert(signed char ch)
{
    return (int)(unsigned char)ch;
}
```

But take care, because there is an overflow with `0xFF` `char` value (255 in decimal).

Comment: In this particular case a union is a bad idea, for two reasons: it won't do the same thing on big-endian architectures (where `.c1` is likely to alias with the *most* significant byte of `.c2`); and the remaining bytes of `.c2` are never initialised.